# What is the difference between pairwise kernels and pairwise distances?

Tags: machine-learning, multiple-comparisons, scikit-learn, kernel-trick, recommender-system

What is the difference between pairwise kernels and pairwise distances?

I frequently came across terms like pairwise kernels and pairwise distances while learning about [Pairwise metrics, Affinities, and Kernels](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/metrics.html#), but I don't get the real meaning of these words and their differences.

Answer (score 4):

I think to start; we should understand concerning **Kernel(-functions)**:

- [How to intuitively explain what a kernel is?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/152897/how-to-intuitively-explain-what-a-kernel-is)
- [Is a kernel function just a mapping?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/379394/is-a-kernel-function-basically-just-a-mapping)
- [What is a kernel function?](https://towardsdatascience.com/kernel-function-6f1d2be6091)

**Pairwise distance** provides distance between two vectors/arrays. So the more pairwise distance, the less similarity while **cosine similarity** is:
$cosine\_similarity = (1 - pairwise\_distance)$, so the more cosine similarity, the more similarity between two vectors/arrays.

Please see the following example to find *Cosine similarity* performance on two random quotes/strings using [TF-IDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255835/cosine-similarity-and-tf-idf):
[image: img]

```py
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

documents = (
    "The Worst Distance Between Two People is Misunderstanding",
    "A Mutual Misunderstanding"    
)

tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
tfidf_matrix = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(documents)

#method 1:
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
print(cosine_similarity(tfidf_matrix[0:1], tfidf_matrix)[0,1])
#0.1505569696020495

#method 2:
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import pairwise_distances
print(pairwise_distances(tfidf_matrix[0:1], tfidf_matrix, metric='cosine')[0,1])
#0.8494430303979505
```

**Note 1:** that according to [documentation](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/main/sklearn/metrics/pairwise.py): *Cosine distance is defined as 1.0 minus the cosine similarity.*

$$Cosine\_distance = (1 - cos(similarity))$$

That explains the difference between the two methods is used for similarity computation for quotes.

**Note 2:** based on [`scikit-learn` documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise_distances.html#sklearn-metrics-pairwise-distances) valid metrics for Pairwise distance are :

> [‘cityblock’, ‘cosine’, ‘euclidean’, ‘l1’, ‘l2’, ‘manhattan’]. These
> metrics support sparse matrix inputs. [‘nan_euclidean’] but it does
> not yet support sparse matrices.

From [`scipy.spatial.distance` documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/spatial.distance.html), valid metrics for Pairwise distance *matrix* are:

> [‘braycurtis’, ‘canberra’, ‘chebyshev’, ‘correlation’, ‘dice’,
> ‘hamming’, ‘jaccard’, ‘kulsinski’, ‘mahalanobis’, ‘minkowski’,
> ‘rogerstanimoto’, ‘russellrao’, ‘seuclidean’, ‘sokalmichener’,
> ‘sokalsneath’, ‘sqeuclidean’, ‘yule’]

**Note 3:** According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55623717/10452700), definitions for *cosine distance* that they used are different in `scipy` & `sklearn`. The one used in `sklearn` is a measure of *similarity* while the one used in `scipy` is a measure of ***dis**similarity*

Concerning **Pairwise distance** measures, which many ML-based algorithms (supervised\unsupervised) use the following distance measures/metrics:

1. Euclidean Distance
2. Cosine Similarity
3. Hamming Distance
4. Manhattan Distance
5. Chebyshev Distance
6. Minkowski
7. Jaccard Index
8. Haversine
9. Sørensen-Dice Index
10. Gower’s Distance

[image: img]
There is also interesting visualization from sklearn [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_agglomerative_clustering_metrics.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-cluster-plot-agglomerative-clustering-metrics-py).

This [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/9-distance-measures-in-data-science-918109d069fa) by *M. Grootendorst* gives you better intuition to understand the choices of distance metrics as well as the advantages and pitfalls of 9 frequently used distance measures in Data Science.

In the case of categorical data, you must convert it to numeric data, either by ranking (for an ordered factor) or by encoding it as a set of binary (dummy) variables. If the data consists of mixed continuous and binary variables, you will usually want to scale the variables so that the ranges are similar; one way is to use *Gower’s distance*. Selecting the proper distance measure resulted in a much better model!

Comment: This doesn't seem to address the original question, which was about the difference between distances and kernel functions

Comment: @user20160 The title of the question is a bit vague. I assumed that OP is interested in the context of **distance metrics** between pairwise kernels and pairwise distances as the link in question discusses this; otherwise, the definition/difference of kernel/pairwise distance does not make any sense! If you have a better explanation for OP, feel free to edit my answer. The understanding of kernel has been addressed at the beginning of the answer and followed by an example to address how distance could be measured pairwisely and finally ended up with some discussion and some references.